# R: Does a time interval fall in another time interval?

Tags: r

I have a database with an id variable and start/end dates for follow up:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data <- tibble(id = c(01, 02, 03, 04),
               start_date = dmy(c('01-02-1997', '05-03-1998', '09-08-2002', '05-05-1997')),
               end_date = dmy(c('03-04-2002', '06-07-2004', '07-04-2010', '03-04-2008')))
```

I want to produce a df that takes a period of time (3 year periods, e.g. y1997.99 = 1997 to 1999) and asks whether the start and end dates fall within this period (e.g. if follow up starts in 1996 and ends in 2000, they would be counted in the 1997 to 1999 and 2000-2003 periods but not the 2003-2006 period).

I want to produce a df such as:

```
data <- tibble(id = c(01, 02, 03, 04),
               start_date = dmy(c('01-02-1997', '05-03-1998', '09-08-2002', '05-05-1997')),
               end_date = dmy(c('03-04-2002', '06-07-2004', '07-04-2010', '03-04-2008')),
               y1997.99 = c(1,1,0,1),
               y2000.03 =c(1,1,1,1),
               y2004.06 =c(0,1,1,1),
               y2007.09 = c(0,0,1,1),
               y2010.12 = c(0,0,1,0),
               y2013.15 = c(0,0,0,0))
```

Does anyone know how this could be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This function does what the question asks for. It splits the names starting with a `"y"` by the period `"."` and creates intervals corresponding to those names in a `lapply` loop. Then sees if the vectors overlap and assembles everything in the return data.frame.

```
fun <- function(data){
  int <- with(data, interval(start_date, end_date))
  nms <- grep("^y", names(data), value = TRUE)
  nms <- sub("^y", "", nms)
  int_nms <- lapply(strsplit(nms, "\\."), function(x){
    cent <- substr(x[1], 1, 2)
    x[2] <- paste0(cent, x[2])
    start <- ISOdate(x[1], "01", "01", 0, 0, 0)
    end <- ISOdate(x[2], "12", "31", 23, 59, 59)
    interval(start, end)
  })
  int_nms2 <- lapply(int_nms, function(i) as.integer(int_overlaps(int, i)))
  tmp <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, int_nms2)
  names(tmp) <- nms
  cbind.data.frame(data[1:3], tmp)
}

fun(data)
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I have created columns for the year periods (e.g `data$y1997.2000`). It is returning the periods when there is no overlap as 0 and giving NAs for periods of overlap. This can be changed easily. Thanks!

Comment: @PJC The name `1997.2000` is not like in the posted data, the function pastes the first 2 digits of the `1997` part with the 2nd part because it has *only 2 digits*. With the new format, remove the first 2 instructions inside the `lapply` loop, the instructions `cent <- ...` and `x[2] <- ...`.

Comment: Apologies for my error in the column names. Your function is working perfectly! Thank so much for your help!